# pip install virtualenvwrapper-win not working

Tags: python, django

pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
after this above command these errors are shown
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenvwrpper-win (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for virtualenvwrpper-win

I cann't solve this problem.

i tried to create a virtual environment wrapper.

Comment: Did you notice the typo in the message?

Comment: it was a mistake. if you understand my problem, then help me.

Comment: Twice? Looks more like you entered the wrong package name.

Comment: i was following a 3 years old youtube video and did exactly the same, but i only got those two errors.

Answer (score 0):

1st update Your pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

or

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

or

```
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

after try this syntax:

```
py -m pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
```

if still doesn't work, before virtualenvwrapper try this:

```
pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

Ofc. it is for windows (try it in shell or cmd as admin)

Comment: No prob! Have fun! You can upvote my answer ;) It helps others with same problem!